# Datamapper Unique Constraint and Paranoid Deletion

Tags: mysql, ruby, datamapper, unique-constraint

I have a datamapper object with a few fields and a unique constraint. Effectively, this ensures that only one record can be created per user ID per date code.

```
class Form
  include Datamapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :username, String, :required => true, :index => true
  property :termcode, Integer, :required => true
  property :status, Enum[:draft, :review, :approved, :denied], :default => :draft
  ...

  property :deleted_at, ParanoidDateTime

  # only one record per user per term code
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :scope => [:termcode], :unless => lambda{|r| r.status == :draft }

end
```

Problem is that if I utilize the paranoid deletion features, the uniqueness constraint prevents additional records from being created with the same data.

For example, if Sue creates a record for the "2015" term code, and deletes it, she's prevented from creating a new one with the same term code because the paranoid functionality persists the original record in the database.

Fields for this model are required for data integrity purposes, and are indexed in many cases as well for sorting and better query optimization.

How do I utilize safe deletion but also allow users to enter more records but tell the unique constraint to ignore the deleted ones?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method and register it before create and before save [as a hook](http://datamapper.org/docs/callbacks.html).

[This is basically the same way the paranoid types operate.](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-types/blob/master/lib/dm-types/paranoid/base.rb)